# ConcurrentLinkedQueue periodically emptied?

Tags: java, queue

I have a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` field in my class and I end up with a really erratic behavior when running a simple monothread test in Eclipse with JUnit.

My class:

```
public class ArchiverData
{
/** The pricing API records */
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ArchiverApiResponseDTO> pricingQueue =
        new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ArchiverApiResponseDTO>();
[...]
public int getApiResponseCount()
{
    return pricingQueue.size();
}

public void addApiResponseDTO(ArchiverApiResponseDTO dto)
{
    pricingQueue.add(dto);
}

public ArchiverApiResponseDTO pollApiResponseDTO()
{
    return pricingQueue.poll();
}
[...]
}
```

My test:

```
public class ArchiverDataTest {
@Test
public void test() {
    ArchiverData archiverData = new ArchiverData();
    ArchiverApiResponseDTO dto = new ArchiverApiResponseDTO([...]);
    archiverData.addApiResponseDTO(dto);
    archiverData.addApiResponseDTO(dto);
    System.out.println(":" + archiverData.getApiResponseCount());
}
}
```

As you can see, there is nothing else running in the Test Case. The `ArchiverApiResponseDTO` object is a simple set of fields.

My results:

- Running the test: `:2` (which is fine)
- Step-by-step debug in IDE: `:0` and the `archiverData.pricingQueue` object looks always empty
- breakpoint on second `addApiResponseDTO` call: `archiverData.pricingQueue` empty; then run: `:1`
- breakpoint on `sysout`: `archiverData.pricingQueue` empty, then run: `:0`

It is important to note that a colleague attempted the same and got correct results (`:2`) each time! I got nothing else running at the same time. It looks like something is emptying my queue when given the time. What on earth is happening?

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue... sounds like you're using multiple threads? Are you sure no other threads (other than the main thread from the test) are runnable? Started in test setup maybe?

Comment: Yes, the queue is supposed to be used in a multithread context, but here, nothing like that, I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess now is that you have a watch on pollApiResponseDTO() or poll() and it's actually your debugger emptying the queue.

Comment: OMG. You are very good :D Well played! I had `pollApiResponseDTO`watched!